# What is the key in complex data type map(object)

Tags: terraform

I am new to terraform and I am trying to understand the below code snippet.
Variable is of type map(objects) and Its looping over map(objects) and keys function takes a map and returns a list containing the keys from that map. Example: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/keys.html

I believe the output will be something like:

```
network_ids = {
  network_alias = 123
  network_alias = 456
  network_alias = 789
}
```

What will be the value for network_alias? I went through many links but I am unable to understand.

```
code snippet:

locals {
  network_ids = {
    for network_alias in keys(var.networks) :
    network_alias => aws_vpc.subnet[network_alias].id
  }
}

variable "networks" {
  type = map(object({
    network_number    = string
    availability_zone = string
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to break this down.

So, to begin with, `network_ids` is a [terraform local value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html). Generally, local values are used to store off computations that you don't want to repeat over and over again.

`network_ids` is specifically a [`map` `for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions). `map` `for` expressions are used to build up `map`s from other, "enumerable" values.

In terraform a `map` is like a HashMap in other languages (`dict` in python, `Hash` in ruby, `HashMap` in Java and so on). `map` contains an association list mapping a unique key (always a `string`) to a value which could be of any, consistent type (meaning you can't have things like `{ "a" = 4, "b" = "c" }` since `4` and `"c"` have different types).

In your specific example, `for network_alias in keys(var.networks)` says, basically

> loop through the keys (again, `string`s) in `var.networks` and bind each one to the name `network_alias`.

The `network_alias => aws_vpc.subnet[network_alias].id` part says

> build a new map where the key is the same as the keys we're looping over, and the value is a lookup of a subnet's ID indexed by the key.

That all being said, `local.network_ids` will not end up looking like the following, because `map`s have distinct keys and the comprehension actually evaluates the key value

```
network_ids = {
  network_alias = 123
  network_alias = 456
  network_alias = 789
}
```

It's impossible for me to tell you exactly what the value will be because I don't know the value of `var.networks` nor that of `aws_vpc.subnet`.

Comment: For looping over maps(strings)
Example {for <KEY>, <VALUE> in <MAP> : <OUTPUT_KEY> => <OUTPUT_VALUE>} variable "hero_thousand_faces" {
  description = "map"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {
    neo      = "hero"
    trinity  = "love interest"
    morpheus = "mentor"
  }
}
output "upper_roles" {
  value = {for name, role in var.hero_thousand_faces : upper(name) => upper(role)}
}
The output from running this code will be:
upper_roles = {
  "MORPHEUS" = "MENTOR"
  "NEO" = "HERO"
  "TRINITY" = "LOVE INTEREST"
}.

Comment: https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9

Comment: When its looping over map(objects), is it going to bind each object to the name network_alias?

Comment: @nadish it depends on _how_ the loop is constructed. If using `keys(var.networks)` like above, it will bind to only the keys in the map. `values(var.networks)` will bind to the actual objects.

Comment: In a `map` `for` expression, you can actually do `{ for k, v in var.my_map : ... }` to loop over the pairs of keys (bound to `k`) and values (bound to `v`) at once.